# c++ template class - class variable in method not available

Tags: c++, templates

I´m totally new to template classes.
I´ve created one, but I have no access to the public class variable in a method.

Program is crashing.
Watch in debug mode: There is no member named q. --> CRASH

Class:

```
#ifndef SIMULATOR_H
#define SIMULATOR_H

#include<queue>
#include<Event.h>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


template<class T>
class Simulator
{
public:
    std::priority_queue<Event<T>*> q;
    int i;
    Simulator()
    {
    }
    virtual ~Simulator()
    {
        //dtor
    }
    void addEvent(Event<T> *e)
    {
        i = 5; //Watch in debug mode: There is no member named i. --> CRASH
        this->q.push(e); //Watch in debug mode: There is no member named q. --> CRASH
    }
};

#endif // SIMULATOR_H
```

main.cpp

```
Simulator<int> *simulator;
simulator->addEvent(event);
```

Comment: Where is the code for your Event class? Where in main is the event object declared?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Simulator<int> *simulator = new Simulator<int>;
simulator->addEvent(event);
```

You created a uninitialised pointer, so program crashes because the pointer does not point to a valid object.

It's better if you avoid use of the pointer, because in this case (without seeing your code) I don't see any reason to use it.